# Separable Functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are Measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

> **Exercise 1.23 (Stein and Shakarchi):** Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is separably continuous: for each fixed variable, $f$ is continuous in the other variable. Prove that $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So far my intuition leads me to use the following property given for measurable functions:

> The finite-valued function $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})$ is measurable for every open set $\mathcal{O}$.

I imagine that we assume $f$ is finite valued, as we almost always find that a function takes on infinite values on at most a set of measure zero (within the context of this text). Now, it is clear that $f$ is measurable on every "horizontal" slice if we were to fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$ due to the continuity of $f$ in $x$. Similarly, on every "vertical" slice $f$ is measurable.

***Now, here is where I find myself stuck, and am asking if my intuition is leading me in the correct direction.*** If we let $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ be arbitrary, then taking the countable union of these horizontal slices (or/and vertical slices if you desire), $f$ remains continuous on this set. I'm assuming that since these slices are dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, due to the density of $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $f$ remains continuous in the closure of this dense set, being $\mathbb{R}^2$. I feel iffy making this logical step, and I feel like I'm missing something.

**Is this the right direction for proving this?** I am approaching this by focusing on the dense subset, as it should be easier than the entirity of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, I'm assuming that this idea generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^d$ through a simple induction proof correct?

Comment: No, separately continuous does not imply continuous.  For example, $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ is separately continuous, but it is not continuous at the point $(0,0)$ since, e.g., $f(x,-x)=\frac12$ for $x\neq 0$ which does not converge to $f(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Ah thank you for the counter example, I felt iffy about implying continuity from each component onto all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I will follow the direction another comment gave in which we go through an approach from what looks like constructing a sequence of measurable functions which converges to $f$, guaranteeing the measurability of a separable function